# Internet Explorer Caching asp.netmvc ajax results

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, internet-explorer, caching, asp.net-ajax

I'm having an issue with a page in internet explorer.
I have an ajax call that calls a form, in other browser, when I click the link it passes in the controller and load correctly data. but in IE, when its loaded once, it aways brings me the same old results without passing in the controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected Caching of AJAX results in IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013637/unexpected-caching-of-ajax-results-in-ie8)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

This attribute, placed in controller class, disables caching. Since I don't need caching in my application, I placed it in my BaseController class:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
```

Here is nice description about OutputCacheAttribute: [Improving Performance with Output Caching](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-15-cs.aspx)

You can place it on action too.

Comment: This should not be the issue because the caching only happens in IE

Comment: @Malcolm Frexner: Caching strategy differs in browsers. There are some problems with IE.

Answer (score 11):

You could try setting  the [`cache`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) option to `false`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/controller/action',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

This option will force the browser not to cache the request.

---

UPDATE:

Based on the comment you could add a unique timestamp to the url to avoid caching issues:

```
var d = new Date();
var myURL = 'http://myserver/controller/action?d=' + 
    d.getDate() + 
    d.getHours() + 
    d.getMinutes() + 
    d.getMilliseconds();
```

Comment: Well, I'm using Microsoft Ajax, not jQuery. ;) This setting works for all ajax based calls? even for msAjax?

Comment: oops, sorry, I've missed this important part of your question.

Comment: I'm upvoting this because this is the correct answer if you're using jQuery.  In fact, if you're using jQuery and not the MS Ajax handlers in MVC, IE will totally ignore all those attributes you set on your methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HttpMethod = "POST"` on your AjaxOptions

```
var ajaxOpts = new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TargetDiv",  HttpMethod = "POST"};
```

like this exp;

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Text","ActionName", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "TargetDiv",  HttpMethod = "POST"})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've blogged about fixing the IE cache issue for both jQuery and the MS client library:

http://yoavniran.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/ie-caching-ajax-results-how-to-fix/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I also found this very useful on a similar (but not identical) issue.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1681358.aspx/1?Disable+cache+in+Ajax+ActionLink+extension+method+in+asp+net+MVC

Basically make sure that you're using POST as opposed to GET in your requests. Doing so seems to prevent IE from caching.

Eg:

@Ajax.ActionLink("Clear Contacts", MVC.Home.ClearContacts(), new AjaxOptions{HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId="targetDiv"})

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Ajax Helper, you can set the `AllowCache` parameter to `false` like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("AjaxCall", "AjaxMethod", "DeconflictedFiles",
                 new { }, 
                 new AjaxOptions
                 {
                     AllowCache = false,
                 })
```

And IE won't cache the results of the call.

Comment: This is not working as expected, I tried it and still it's cached

Answer (score 0):

actually in IE browser caching not clear automatically.
but in chrome scripts working accepted.so you need to try for
clearing data in browser level.