# ActionLink called only once in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC blog app that makes a call to Ajax for updating a flag.

In IE (and only in IE, in other browsers it runs fine), I can call an `ActionLink` only once. If I click after the first time, the ajax action in the controller is not invoked.

Here is the partial part of code of the View:

```
<div id="news_comment_state_@(Model.Id)">@(Model.FlControlled==false?"Da approvare":@Model.FlApproved?"Approvato":"Respinto")</div>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Approva", "ApproveDenyComment", new { IdComment = Model.Id, ApproveDeny = true }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "news_comment_state_"+@Model.Id})
    <br />
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Respingi", "ApproveDenyComment", new { IdComment = Model.Id, ApproveDeny = false }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "news_comment_state_"+@Model.Id})
```

If I put a breakpoint in the controller it is fired only once per Link, then it is never called again. Where is the error? Maybe cache problem?

Comment: Sounds like cache. Add a random integer to the end to make sure you get a fresh request.

Comment: you're right, it was cache. Tejs, if you add an answer i mark it as accepted. Thanks very much!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16299281/2057154

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like cache. Add a random integer to the end to make sure you get a fresh request.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to avoid the caching problem is to add the following to the line above your method in the controller:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult MyMethod() {
    ...
}
```

This will make sure it runs the server-side code.