# ASP.NET MVC - Prevent Cache on Ajax.ActionLinks

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, browser-cache

Is there anyway to disable the cache when using Ajax.ActionLink. Im having problems in IE whereby If I remove an item, which uses an ajax actionlink, it then reloads the partial view which the item is contained, and the item re-appears there (even tho it has been removed)
On other browser's it works fine and as intended

```
   @Ajax.ActionLink("x", "RemoveItem", new { id = item.QuoteLineID, enquiryId = item.EnquiryID }, new AjaxOptions()
   {
       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
       UpdateTargetId = "Summary"
   }, new { @class = "delete-link" })
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16299281/2057154

Comment: Hi, Yeah, I commented that making it POST solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031487/asp-net-mvc-prevent-cache-on-ajax-actionlinks?noredirect=1#comment11327530_9031542

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult RemoveItem(int id, int enquiryId)
{
    ...
}
```

or append a random parameter to the request using the `routeValues` argument.

Comment: This doesnt work, I've tried it, seems to be related to just IE

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff, then try appending a random number as an additional query string parameter when generating the link.

Comment: I solved it, I used HttpMethod = "POST" in the AjaxOptions. Seems to have done the trick

Comment: I wonder if one has to add this cruft to *every* ajax action now, to solve the issue...

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I used this but it's not working on `Windows Safari 5.1.7` and Mac Safari also. Can you please help me in this.

Answer (score 7):

I know you said you solved it by using HttpPost, but just in case that doesn't end up being the preferred solution, this works for me;

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string param1)
{
     Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by using :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Disable browser cache Ajax.ActionLinks
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    });
</script>
```