# Invalid JSON Primitive in IE8 version 8.0.7600 and lower

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, internet-explorer-8

I am getting the error or "Invalid JSON Promitive: undefined" when making an ajax request in IE8 versions 8.0.7600 and lower but cant replicate it in 8.0.7601 or higher.  Does anyone know why or how to fix it?

```
$.ajax({
    url: defaults.url + (defaults.url.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'r=' + Math.random(),
    type: defaults.method,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: defaults.dataType,
    data: ko.toJSON(defaults.data),
    beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("URL_REFERRER", config.urlReferrer);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
    },
)}
```

**Controller**

```
public virtual JsonResult CompleteOrder(string id)
{
    _entitlementsService.CompleteOrder(AuthenticateManager.CurrentUserProfile.UserModel.UserId, id);
    return Json(new SuccessResponse("Order completed"));
}
```

**Request**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:16253/DashboardSetup/Entitlements/CompleteOrder/c8e053d9-a458-11e1-8dd0-001cc4565d26?r=0.8639180345926434
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json
Cookie:MYNGCONNECT=56053B332B26A0FD9D0A31C5FC83868281D876DB1F365034306F6CB3A64C5B2F7
Host:localhost:16253
Origin:http://localhost:16253
Referer:http://localhost:16253/DashboardSetup/Entitlements/Entitlement?SearchResults=True&id=c8e053d9-a458-11e1-8dd0-001cc4565d26
URL_REFERRER:http://localhost:16253/DashboardSetup/Entitlements
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview URL encoded
r:0.8639180345926434
```

Comment: is it with your `data` in your ajax post or anyother?

Comment: I am sending data, but I just kept replicate it because I dont have that version of IE8.

Comment: Can you post that part of your code? I mean `data`

Comment: It is still not clear about your `defaults.data` .. whether a string or object.. If an object, try stringify the Object as you are using Knockout.js ..you can use `ko.utils.stringifyJson`.. Just a Try... Am not sure ..I used to face the similar problem.

Comment: Thing is I cant even replicate it on my end since I dont have that version of IE8.  It clearly states on knockouts website "ko.toJSON — this produces a JSON string representing your view model’s data. ".  defaults.data is a JSON object.

Comment: Can you post the JSON? I bet its something with escape characters

Comment: There is no JSON, just a POST.  There are other requests that contain JSON, but this one in particular doesn't.

Comment: The heck are you trying to do here? `defaults.url + (defaults.url.indexOf('?') > 0 ? '&' : '?') + 'r=' + Math.random(),` If you dont want a cache, merely do `cache:false`

Comment: cache:false doesnt help in IE.

Comment: @MikeFlynn It helps, if you have properly configured backend.

Comment: Maybe, but Ive tried to add all the cache expiration tags and what not and IE just wont have it.  Other browsers work fine.  I just read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013637/unexpected-caching-of-ajax-results-in-ie8, and it seems that cache: false does the exact same thing I do.  Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your contentType to "text/json" or "text/plain". Older IE needs different content type disposition in header.