# JQUERY AJAX Not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unexpected Caching of AJAX results in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013637/unexpected-caching-of-ajax-results-in-ie8)

I am using jquery / ajax to bring in data from another page on my site.

The code is...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
     setInterval(function() {
     $('#homenews').load('investor/news_releases.php #content_wide .newspost:lt(2)');
     }, 3000); 
   });
</script>
```

Working fine in other browsers but just not IE.

Any ideas?

Comment: ... any errors in the console? ... did you fire up developer tools to see any debugging messages?

Comment: $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); is meant to fix the Caching issue. No debugging errors :-(

Comment: in the #homenews div the current (loading..) content disappears...but the new content is not inputted.