# Jquery sometimes not working with ie8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have this code to get value from server request

```
var itemPackage = ddlPackages.value;

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data: ({ itemPacking: itemPackage }),
    url: '/List/ItemCurrentQty/',

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    context: this,
    timeout: 5000,


    success: function (data) {
        $('#OutQty').data('tTextBox').maxValue = data[0].CurrentQty;
        $('#CurrStockQty').text(data[0].CurrentQty);

    }
});
```

the  `$('#CurrStockQty')` text not updated with ie8 but it's ok with google chrom
any Idea please?

Comment: try `$('#CurrStockQty').html("test");`

Comment: From your comment below Siwei Shen's answer: _"it seems not call the function (ItemCurrentQty) which get new value from server"_ - can you confirm that? If you replace the contents of the success handler with `alert(data)` does the alert display each time or just the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that your success function is firing before data is returned from server . Did you try to put alert on  success ?

```
   success: function (data) {
       alert(data[0].CurrentQty);
    }
```

If thats case than make the ajax call synschronous by adding a parameter to ajax async : false;

Comment: I used alert(data[0].CurrentQty) in success handler and noticed that: it's called every time but with first value i got it from server, this mean it's not call function (ItemCurrentQty) which get new value from server except first time , the strange thing .. it works with chrom and firefox , the problem only with ie8

Comment: Do you have enabled caching in any way to page that you are making call to ? Its possible . Add cache: false parameter to ajax call . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013637/unexpected-caching-of-ajax-results-in-ie8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013637/unexpected-caching-of-ajax-results-in-ie8

Comment: Thats same link that I sent in comment . Not sure why you are posing it again .