# IE 11 opens the old overwritten PDF instead of the new PDF?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

## EDIT:

I edited this setting in Internet Explorer. Internet Options-> General (Tab) -> Settings (Button) -> Temporary Internet Files(Tab) -> Select "Every Time I visit this page". It now loads the right PDF every time but it doesn't help out my users. I also tried adding `cache:false` to my ajax call in JQuery.

---

The code below works great in Firefox and in Chrome. Both of those browsers open the new PDF into a new tab every time no problems. Unfortunately Internet Explorer prompts to either open or save the PDF and upon selecting open it shows you the old 0.pdf instead of the one you just created. If you select to save the PDF and then open it from the desktop it overwrites no problem. (Note: open still works the first time for every user session but every time after that until log out it will show the first PDF generated when you select to open instead of Save)

So is there a way to have Internet Explorer recognize that the PDF has been overwritten on the server and open the new PDF instead of the old PDF?

---

c# code that generates a new PDF that has the same file name as the previous PDF so it overwrites the previously generated PDF.

```
//...get data for variables

string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf");

creator.PrintLabels(labels, new labelFormat(), path, startingLabelPosition);

string relativePath = @"\DesktopModules\DataManagement\Pdf\" + 0 + ".pdf";

return relativePath;
```

I also use this jquery/ajax code to open the newly created PDF into a new window.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DesktopModules/DataManagement/TestService.svc/CreateLabelPdf",
    data: JSON.stringify(labelInfo),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        window.open(data.d);
    },
    error:  function(msg) {
        alert("Error: " + msg.status);
    }
});
```

Comment: are you sure it isn't a cache issue?

Comment: I just cleared my cache and the problem still persists. assuming safety > Delete Browsing History > 'checked all except the top box' would clean my cache

Comment: Did you try this setting: Internet Options-> General (Tab) -> Settings (Button) -> Temporary Internet Files(Tab) -> Select "Every Time I visit this page".

Comment: @JonHarding You were right. When I disabled  Internet Options-> General (Tab) -> Settings (Button) -> Temporary Internet Files(Tab) -> Select "Every Time I visit this page". The right PDF's started to show. But how can I do that for all of my users instead of just doing that for myself?

Also I thought POST Ajax requests don't get cached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked was very close to what [Danyu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083441/1184321) suggested.

It turns out that IE was not caching the request but caching the actual PDF so that each time it tried to load up 0.pdf it found the one that it had previously found and loaded that. So instead of changing the request to the server I had to change the file path that the web browser was taking to the file. I did this by appending the query string.

So I had to initialize `var math = Math.random();` and then add `+"?identification="+math` into `window.open(data.d)`

Final Code:

```
var math = Math.random();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DesktopModules/DataManagement/TestService.svc/CreateLabelPdf",
    data: JSON.stringify(labelInfo),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        window.open(data.d+"?identification="+math);
    },
    error:  function(msg) {
        alert("Error: " + msg.status);
    }
});
```

Comment: You just described exactly what @Danyu suggested in the other answer, you just opted to use a randomized number rather than a timestamp. I don't know why you posted your own version of the answer rather than just accepting the one that actually suggested this.

Comment: @sphanley ? He suggested that my request was getting cached and  that I should add code to the `url:` in the ajax request, when in reality it was the PDF that was being cached and required the code to be added in a different place to reflect that difference. 

The reason I didn't accept his answer is because his answer did not answer my question.

Perhaps I should have just edited in the exact solution into my question and accepted his answer but I don't necessarily think that is better or more easy to read than just giving the full answer as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

It could happen, when your request string (especially those have no parameter) does not change.
You could append a dummy parameter that changes every time, like current time stamp, into your url.

For example:

```
  url: "DesktopModules/DataManagement/TestService.svc/CreateLabelPdf?dummy="+currentTimeStamp,
```

Comment: adding the query string is what makes the cache happen.  Of course if you change the query string every time this will prevent the caching that would occur from the same query string every time.  But NONE OF THIS will happen without any query string .  This is NOT something you should incorporate as a permanent solution.  OP needs to figure out what is causing this behavior

Comment: Did you try this setting: Internet Options-> General (Tab) -> Settings (Button) -> Temporary Internet Files(Tab) -> Select "Every Time I visit this page".

Comment: @Danyu that did the trick. However, how can I solve that for all my users instead of just myself? I looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013637/unexpected-caching-of-ajax-results-in-ie8?rq=1) and it didn't help

Comment: Did you try your application in chrome?

Comment: It seems that if IE sees the same query being fired twice, the cached result is grabbed from local and displayed right away to improve the performance. I had this issue in my project before and what I did is to add a dummy parameter that changes all the time, which apparently is not recommanded by @ScottSelby. But you can try it and make your decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just modify the htaccess file to

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  # Enable expirations.
  ExpiresActive On

<FilesMatch ".(pdf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0"
</FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```